# GxFilterWorkspace allows a folder that is not a IWorkspace or IGxDatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, browser

I am trying to open a ArcGIS file browser. And For this, I used [IGxDialog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0015000000qv000000) interface's [DoModalOpen](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/DoModalOpen_Method/0015000000r0000000/) method. To specify what the user can select using a GxDialog browser is based on the filters (GxObjectFilter) held by the object. To browse workspace, I set ObjectFilter to GxFilterWorkspaces. But it allows folders that contains layers/feature classes/raster datasets that is not IGxDatabase or IWorkspace.

```
        IGxObjectFilter gxObjectFilter = new GxFilterWorkspaces();
        IGxDialog gxDialog = new GxDialog();
        gxDialog.AllowMultiSelect = false;
        gxDialog.Title = title;
        gxDialog.ObjectFilter = gxObjectFilter;
        gxDialog.ButtonCaption = "Open";
        gxDialog.RememberLocation = true;

        IEnumGxObject enumGxObject;
        gxDialog.DoModalOpen(0, out enumGxObject);
        while ((gxObject = enumGxObject.Next()) != null)
        {
            if ((gxObject as IGxDatabase2) != null)
            {
                return gxObject.FullName;
            }
        }
```

**Question:**

What should I do to select only workspace through this browser? Or is there any other option to browse GIS dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A folder is also a workspace (e.g. for shapefiles).

I do not think there is a built-in filter for selecting geodatabases (if that's what you mean). You can pretty easily implement `IGxObjectFilter` yourself, though.